# How to correctly include offset in Bayesian Zero-Inflated Poisson model in winbugs

Tags: bayesian, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, jags, bugs

I am trying to fit a Bayesian Zero-inflated model and I want to include an offset term.
When I compared the output of the pscl package; the result of the count model from the winbugs and pscl package were similar. While the results of the zero-inflated part from the bayesian model and pscl package were quite disimilar.

The problem is how to include the offset on zero-inflated part.

```
model{
## Likelihood
for(i in 1:N){
count[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
lambda[i] <- lambda.new[i]*(1-zero.count[i]) + 1e-10*zero.count[i]
log(lambda.new[i]) <- beta[1] + beta[2]*edu[i] + log(person_time[i])

## Zero-Inflation
zero.count[i] ~ dbern(pi[i])
pi[i] <- ilogit(pi.new[i])
# I am not quite certain if this is correctly specified
pi.new[i] <- alpha[1] + alpha[2]*edu[i] + log(person_time[i]) 
} 
## Priors
beta ~ dmnorm(0,1.0E-6)
alpha ~ dmnorm(0,1.0E-6)
}
```

Please I can I correctly specify the offset for the zero inflation part in the model above so as to obtain similar result as produced by the zeroinfl function in pscl package?

Comment: The results of the count model are similar *to what*? The results of the zero-inflated part are different *from what*?

Comment: I compared the Bayesian output and frequentist output ( pscl package)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some deep thinking about counting mixture processes with imbalanced design. The wrinkle of unequal follow-up duration needs a clearly specified model. Simply adding `log(person_time)` to the binary zero vs. Poisson part is not the right approach. The implication, in fact, is that observing a zero-generator longer means they would be *more* likely to spontaneously generate counts, which is the exact opposite of what you're trying to do.

The Poisson process benefits greatly from the memoryless interarrival times of events. As a result, you can slice-and-dice or aggregate counts over intervals without having issues of correlated data through repeated measures. e.g. a person followed ten years can be compared to a person followed one year through a simple offset.

But what can we say of the precision or confidence in our zero count in following someone for 10 years without a single count versus someone we follow over 1 year with as many? Surely we are more *confident* of their follow-up suggesting they are actually a zero-count generator. A pseudolikelihood approach might say that the person observed 10 years did, say, 10 Bernoulli trials and all came up negative.

In other words, we modify the `dbern` statement. The likelihood becomes:

$$\log d(\pi_i, T_i) = T_i \times \left( \log \pi_i + \log (1-\pi_i)\right)$$

But as a function of covariates, the nonlinear model for $\pi$ should *not* be a function of follow-up time.

$$\text{logit } (\pi )= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{education}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight